# Low wither skeleton spawn rates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a fortress and when I found it, I first built a blaze farm, however, when I started needing Wither Skeleton Skulls, I went into the fortress looking for Wither Skeletons but only found 2 while there were so many blazes spawning. I had a few torches and other than in the safe space the whole fortress was under light level 7.

Answer (score 1):

Mob spawning is random—it is entirely possible that you just got unlucky, and more blazes spawned instead of wither skeletons.

Another explanation could be that the mob cap is being taken up elsewhere. This would lower rates overall inside the fortress. The excessive amount of blazes could be from the spawners, which spawn mobs independently of the mob cap.